# Sharepoint Breadcrumb showing the old/original Page Title

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I have a Sharepoint 2007 site that is displaying the old/original title in the Breadcrumb rather then the updated Page title... help!

Under "Site Content and Structure" I went to "[SiteName] > Pages > [Page] > Edit Page Settings..." which took me to "Page Settings". Here I edited "Page Title and Description > Title" to the new title, simple and done. But the site Breadcrumb is still showing the old title!??!

When I go into "Site Content and Structure > [SiteName] > Settings > Site Settings... > Navigation", under "Navigation Editing and Sorting" I get the list of Pages with their old titles (as is being displayed in the Breadcrumb). As they are Pages the "Edit..." button is disabled so I cannot change their titles here.

I cannot believe a bug this stupid made it into a major release! It's pretty obovious the page titles are being cached somewhere at creation and not updated later. It's this cache that the Navigation is using rather then the current page titles. But I have been unable to locate this mythical cache. And it doesn't look like I can access the sitemap.xml at my access level (grr!), can I get to this via the webUI (I've always done it in the source directories, which I cannot see).

So... where in the hell is the Breadcrumb getting the page titles from, and can I change this (preferably non-programaticially as I am but a simple MOSS editor on this project)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are able to access the Site Collection Administration at the top level, you can access the Site collection object cache, the site collection cache profiles, and the site collection output cache. If you go into the settings of these items, you can check a box to "flush" the cache, that should reset it.

Comment: After 24/48 or so hours it did indeed reset, so I'd imagine that the cron job finally ran on the box to do the flush auto-magically. I don't have the access, but I'm sure your suggestion would work! So Thanks! To the rest who have the issue... at some point Sharepoint will eventually decide to flush the caches.